# Delhpi 11.3 with IOS16 getting WI-FI properties

Tags: ios, ip, ssid

I'm working with Delphi 11.3 for Android and IOS and I need to know the Wi-Fi properties such as SSID and IP, on Android it's very easy but on IOS I'm having difficulties, all the alternatives I find are already obsolete and no longer work, really. I don't know where else to look, can anyone give me some direction?

I have already tested some libraries like Kastri but I was not successful

Comment: I'm writing an app that registers IOT devices on the user's Wi-Fi network, so the logic is to get the phone's SSID, the user enters the Wi-Fi password, after that the app accesses the IOT device through the bluetooth to send the SSID and password data

Comment: The definitely read that link and also [this one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734348)  and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734344) which covers approaches to configuring a WiFi accessory.  Also [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3111-ios-wifi-api-overview) which leads you to [fetchCurrent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/3666511-fetchcurrent) - You will need to find some way of calling this from Delphi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native function for getting the current WiFi SSID is [`fetchCurrent()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nehotspotnetwork/3666511-fetchcurrent) on `NEHotspot`

Note that the documentation for this method states that your app must meet *all four of the following criteria*

> - The app is using the Core Location API and has user’s authorization to access precise location.
> - The app used the NEHotspotConfiguration API to configure the current Wi-Fi network.
> - The app has active VPN configurations installed.
> - The app has an active NEDNSSettingsManager configuration installed.

This is incorrect.  You don't need to meet all four criteria.  You must meet *one* of the four criteria.  In your case you would need to ask for and receive location permission.

Additionally, you need to add the "Access Wi-Fi Information" capability to your project in Xcode.

I know that you asked about Delphi specifically, and I'm afraid I can't help you there, but hopefully the details of how it is done natively will help you.

Getting the IP address is much more difficult.  The general advice from [this developer thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734295) is *Don't try and get the device IP address*.  It is not as straight-forward as it may seem at first glance; Devices have multiple active network interfaces.

Since you have a Bluetooth connection to your device, it is probably simpler to ask the device for its IP address once it has joined the Wifi Network successfully.  Alternatively use Bonjour to discover the device.

There is also a [useful thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734344) in the Apple Developer Forums that suggest some other approaches to accessory configuration.